# Can we establish a connection-less or connection-oriented nature of a connection between 2 computers connected via bluetooth?

Tags: c#, network-programming, bluetooth, network-protocols, networkstream

This sounds a silly question, but I'm trying to create a network between 3 computers over bluetooth, can we try to establish a connection-less or connection-oriented connection between each node, just like we do in IP networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible to do peer to peer networking with bluetooth, the how depends on your OS,

here are a few examples,

Linux
http://giovanni.wordpress.com/2007/04/06/how-to-use-tcpip-over-bluetooth/

Windows
http://www.conniq.com/Windows-networking/Bluetooth_PAN_xp-setup_12.htm

Android
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6072/is-it-possible-to-have-a-tcp-ip-network-using-bluetooth

Note:

this will depend on the profiles your BT device/stack supports,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile

the LAN access profile lets a bluetooth device access the internet via a bluetooth enabled router or access point.

The PAN (personal area network) profile will allow you to do what you are describing. It essentially looks like Ethernet, so you can do anything with it. of course for what your describing you will need static ip addresses, but then you should be able to ping, make sockets, whatever.

Again the device and the OS has to support this profile, but most should.

Comment: Thank you very much those links directed me to whole lot of new and useful information. In IP networks we can use UDP for connection-less and TCP connection-full connectivity, is there any thing like specifically we can use when connecting bluetooth peers? I'm sorry if the question has no base at all - since I'm still learning this. Thanks

Comment: your welcome, I added a bit more detail to my answer. good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan I think I have a clear idea for an approach now. If you know any tools, libraries such as 32Feet.NET or how to program applications for creating computer networks in a PAN (running Win7 with Microsoft Bluetooth Stack) code example etc. kindly let me know. Thanks again.